# What is lavaboom registration token

Tags: email, authentication, lavaboom

I am trying to sign up for [Lavaboom](https://lavaboom.com/en/) email account. When I do, it asks for registration token. What is that? I tried putting some random words in it, but it responded that the token is invalid. What kind of restrictions does it have?

Comment: Is this even a programming question? Probably it's their server error.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about signing up for a service not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definately the wrong section to post this, but they aparantly have a waiting list, so you have to wait for them to send you an email with your registration token to be able to complete your registration.